# Load assembly in Startup.cs .net core 2.1

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core-2.1

i have nugget packages in a folder called nuqkgs and on project start up i want to load these packages(there dll's) into the project to use at run time.

i use the following code to load them, and when i debug i can see the info and that the dll's are found and opened, however when they should be used i get the error that the dll can not be found, and i can see that the solution try's to look for them in the bin folder(they are located solution/nuqkgs/)

i do NOT want to register the packages in any file i simply want to be able to drop a nugget package into the nuqkgs folder and it gets registered automaticaly

Any ideas or anyone that has done this in core 2.1?

This i my startup.cs:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
            options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
        });

        IList<Assembly> components = new List<Assembly>();
        foreach (string file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(@"C:\Users\myName\source\repos\core2.1test\core2.1test\nuqkgs\", "*.nupkg", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
        {
            using (ZipArchive nuget = ZipFile.Open(file, ZipArchiveMode.Read))
            {
                foreach (ZipArchiveEntry entry in nuget.Entries)
                {
                    if (entry.Name.Contains(".dll"))
                    {
                        using (BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(entry.Open()))
                        {
                            components.Add(Assembly.Load(reader.ReadBytes((int)entry.Length)));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        services.AddMvc()
          .ConfigureApplicationPartManager(apm =>
          {
              foreach (var c in components)
              {
                  var part = new AssemblyPart(c);
                  var des = part.Assembly.Location.ToString();
                  apm.ApplicationParts.Add(part);
              }
          }).SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
 }
```

Comment: This is just a seriously bad plan overall. I get the idea of what you're going for, but dynamic references are just going to make your code stupidly complex. For one, you have to go dynamic all the way, which means all code that uses any of these dynamically loaded assemblies will have to be called via reflection, as well. Your code is just going to be a mess of string references, that will be brittle as hell, and all your errors will be runtime errors rather than compile-time errors, like you'd actually want.

Comment: it will be used for plugin architecture-ed solution so all error will be caught on compile in the individual nugget before dropped into the folder

Comment: Sorry several things I don't understand what dose nugget has to do with this? And are you planning to do live addition of dll's or just once per start up?

Comment: as you can see in the code, there is a nugget in a folder, i exstract that nugget and want to register and use the dll´s in each package. If  we would add another nugget package into the folder we would restart the application and it should get registered

Comment: Nope. By definition, you're loading the assemblies at runtime so there's absolutely no way you can catch errors at compile-time. During compile, the application(s) won't have any idea any of this code or references exist.

Comment: As described in the [docs for `AssemblyLoadContext`](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/Documentation/design-docs/assemblyloadcontext.md), `Assembly.Load(byte[])` loads the assembly in a new unnamed load context, and `AssemblyLoadContext` currently cannot resolve dependencies. That's probably why your parts don't work. Try using `AssemblyLoadContext.Default.LoadFromStream` instead of `Assembly.Load(byte[])`.

Comment: @AntonTykhyy you suggestion worked, i will post the code. Thank you for your help

Comment: I posted it as an answer - if you are satisfied with it, please accept it)

Comment: 1. Why don't you want to add references?, and 2. If you're making a plugin system then you should either be using MEF (Managed Extensibility Framework)

Answer (score 2):

As described in the [docs for `AssemblyLoadContext`](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/Documentation/design-docs/assemblyloadcontext.md), `Assembly.Load(byte[])` loads the assembly in a new unnamed load context, and `AssemblyLoadContext` (except the default one) currently cannot resolve dependencies. That's probably why your parts don't work. Try using `AssemblyLoadContext.Default.LoadFromStream` instead of `Assembly.Load(byte[])`.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working, the way i use it now:

1. Open the nuget foreach DLL and I write the dll to a file on the disk.
2. Open the file in a memory stream and read it into memory and from there it can be used in my application.

Alternatively to step 2 you could use :

```
AssemblyLoadContext.Default.LoadFromAssemblyPath(createPathSource);
```

that way you refer to the dll file when using it in your solution

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        IList<Assembly> components = new List<Assembly>();

        foreach (string file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(@"C:\Users\userName\source\repos\core2.1test\core2.1test\nuqkgs\", "*.nupkg", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
        {
            using (ZipArchive nuget = ZipFile.Open(file, ZipArchiveMode.Read))
            {
                foreach (ZipArchiveEntry entry in nuget.Entries)
                {
                    if (entry.Name.Contains(".dll"))
                    {
                        string createPathSource = @"C:\Users\userName\source\repos\core2.1test\core2.1test\nuqkgs\"+ entry.Name;

                        using (BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(entry.Open()))
                        {
                            // Step 1
                            using (FileStream fsNew = new FileStream(createPathSource, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
                            {
                                fsNew.Write(reader.ReadBytes((int)entry.Length), 0, (int)entry.Length);
                            }

                            // Step 2
                            using (FileStream readStream = File.Open(createPathSource, FileMode.Open))
                            {
                                var assempbly = AssemblyLoadContext.Default.LoadFromStream(readStream);
                                components.Add(assempbly);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);

        services.AddMvc()
          .ConfigureApplicationPartManager(apm =>
          {
              foreach (var c in components)
              {
                  var part = new AssemblyPart(c);
                  apm.ApplicationParts.Add(part);
              }
          });
    }
```