# ASP .NET Core MVC add views from `*.views.dll` file while it is running without embedded resource

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I've been trying to import in a ASP.NET Core MVC view of the already compiled view `*.Views.dll` between the possible views.

**Caution!**

I have no intention of adding the `*.views.dll` file among the resources being compiled but afterwards.

To make things clear, the running program must take the file from a folder and read it by adding the contents of the assembly file to its views

To get more information I'll give you the link of the speech in the qule is connected

In addition I do not want to use the embedded resource because the view remains clear.

[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52722484/net-core-2-1-mvc-views-in-plugin)

I tried this

```
    services.AddMvc().ConfigureApplicationPartManager(apm =>{
            var part = new AssemblyPart(AssemblyLoadContext.Default.LoadFromAssemblyPath("C:\\Users\\gianf\\source\\repos\\ViewTestPlugin2\\plug\\bin\\Debug\\netcoreapp2.1\\plug.Views.dll"));
            apm.ApplicationParts.Add(part);
        });
```

Resolved!!!

looking at the assembly of the * .views.dll file I noticed this

```
[assembly: ProvideApplicationPartFactory("Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApplicationParts.CompiledRazorAssemblyApplicationPartFactory, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor")]
```

so as a result I tried to manually set it like this:

```
    services.AddMvc().ConfigureApplicationPartManager(apm =>
    {
        var a = new CompiledRazorAssemblyApplicationPartFactory();
        foreach (var b in a.GetApplicationParts(AssemblyLoadContext.Default.LoadFromAssemblyPath("C:\\Users\\gianf\\source\\repos\\ViewTestPlugin2\\plug\\bin\\Debug\\netcoreapp2.1\\plug.Views.dll")))
            apm.ApplicationParts.Add(b);
    });
```

and so it works, I think AssemblyPart is broken

Comment: Use an [EmbeddedFileProvider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.fileproviders.embeddedfileprovider?view=aspnetcore-2.1)?

Comment: no because the views remain clear

Comment: [AssemblyLoadContext.Default.LoadFromAssemblyPath](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.loader.assemblyloadcontext.loadfromassemblypath?view=netcore-2.1) ? But you'd have to do it very early in your application and (iirc) can't do that after the application started, since the IoC is configured and built already at that point

Comment: @Tseng it's what I use to read the file as an assembly but then as I add the razorpage contained to the mvc service provider?

Comment: ASP.NET Core should do that on startup, that's why I said you have to do it very early, like in `Main` method. Also make sure to use `AssemblyLoadContext.Default' as according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51264344/455493) only from there it will be discovered by the DI/IoC system

Comment: @Tseng I tried and it does not work now I add my test to the question